# How can I allow my slack app to interact with a google sheet on a company account?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack, slack-api

I'm making a Slack slash command that writes to a Google sheet. The slash command and Google sheet are for my company, so the Google sheet is on the company domain. When I try to deploy the Google App Script as a web app, I don't have the option to set the permissions to "Anyone, including anonymous." I only have the option to set it to "Anyone within [COMPANY NAME].com." Using this setting causes a 401 client error when I try to use the slash command on slack. Is there a way for me to get around this?

Comment: You need to adjust your security settings in G Suite to allow for sharing outside of 
 your organization. https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781

Comment: What if I don't have this option? The administrator didn't want to allow that option for security reasons. Is there a way to somehow register the slack app as an authorized user? EDIT: Is it possible to change the security settings for just one file, or will the setting apply to all company documents?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would discuss with your administrator and see what can be done. Your other option is to simply create the script using a personal Google account.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Under the project settings, tick `Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor`
2. Edit the permissions in that file by hand to the following:

```
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  }
```

3. Make a new deployment